# Boost MySQL query with lot LIKE conditions

Tags: mysql

Have a table with ~25K rows, the user can provide keywords and negative keywords to filter rows.
It slows down when a user added a lot of keywords and/or negative keywords.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT id, title, description
FROM entities
WHERE 
(
    title LIKE '%keyword_1%' OR description LIKE '%keyword_1%' 
    OR title LIKE '%keyword_2%' OR description LIKE '%keyword_2%' 
    OR title LIKE '%keyword_3%' OR description LIKE '%keyword_3%' 
)
AND
(
    title NOT LIKE '%negative_keyword_1%' OR description NOT LIKE '%negative_keyword_1%' 
    OR title NOT LIKE '%negative_keyword_2%' OR description NOT LIKE '%negative_keyword_2%' 
    OR title NOT LIKE '%negative_keyword_3%' OR description NOT LIKE '%negative_keyword_3%' 
)
```

for example, a query with 9 keywords and 130 negative keywords takes ~7 seconds.
Maybe there is a better solution to filter those rows without LIKE? maybe the whole logic is wrong.

Tried MATCH () AGAINST() - it is slower than LIKE for some reason.

Comment: Did you try adding a full-text index when using MATCH AGAINST? Normal indexes are of no use when using LIKE '% %'.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Yes, I mentioned in the description, it's much slower than LIKE.

Comment: That is very unlikely. That is why I asked if you just run a query or altered your table to add the correct index first.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow vasyl! if full text search can't cover your need, i believe you should consider the right tool for the job, something like [tag:solr] or [tag:elasticsearch].

Comment: seems like you could just read all 25k rows in less than 7 seconds; consider doing your filtering in the client.  how big is your data?

Answer (score 0):

For such cases like yours it might help to try to filter the positive matches in database and then test them for a presence of a negative keyword in memory. So try something like:

```
SELECT id, title, description
FROM entities
WHERE 
(
    title LIKE '%keyword_1%' OR description LIKE '%keyword_1%' 
    OR title LIKE '%keyword_2%' OR description LIKE '%keyword_2%' 
    OR title LIKE '%keyword_3%' OR description LIKE '%keyword_3%' 
)
```

This gives you results which match positive keywords. You can then filter out the matches in memory which contain negative keywords.

Also give an index a chance to be used with `LIKE`. This reduces your search options from `CONTAINS` to `STARTS WITH` but it might be sufficient for your case. Syntax is `LIKE 'keyword_1%'`.

**Fulltext search**

Another option is to use MySQL fulltext search by defining a fulltext index on your `title` and `description` columns.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_title ON entities(title);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_description ON entities(description);
```

Or you can merge these two columns into a single column - for the search purposes. Then you need only one fulltext index.

Query syntax is then following:

```
MATCH (title) AGAINST ('keyword_1')
```

instead of

```
title LIKE '%keyword_1%'
```

For this search I would also recommend to filter positive matches only in a database and then filter out the matches in memory which contain negative keywords.

Comment: For some reason, full-text search work even slower, if I add 30 keywords and 100 negative keywords.

here is something I forgot to mention:
- it should support pagination
- this functionality used by thousands of users, web app developed with PHP, data stored in MySQL 5.7


I'll investigate tools for search: SphinxSearch, ElasticSearch


do you have recommendations on these or other tools? pros & cons for these tools?